# lag value by group with incomplete and irregular time variable

Tags: r, grouping, lag

I have a df which looks like more or less like that:

```
year <- c(2000,2000,2000,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2006,2006,2006)
type <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
value <- c(71,80,99,79,61,62,56,88,50,85,56,85)
df <- data.frame(year, type, value)
rm(year, type, value)
```

I am trying to do a graph like that:

[image]

which indicate for each group (A,B,C) the change (%) with the previous year.
The problem is that sometimes the precedent year is -1 sometimes -2 or -3 etc...

To do such graph I need to compute the lag value, and then the percentage difference as follow:

```
year  type  value   lag     %
2000    A   71      
2000    B   80      
2000    C   99      
2002    A   79       8       0,112676056
2002    B   61      -19     -0,2375
2002    C   62      -37     -0,373737374
2003    A   56      -23     -0,291139241
2003    B   88       27      0,442622951
2003    C   50      -12     -0,193548387
2006    A   85       29      0,517857143
2006    B   56      -32     -0,363636364
2006    C   85       35      0,7
```

My question is divided in 2:

1. how do you compute the lag value properly?
2. is there a quick way to compute the % change with the previous year as ref?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by a group by 'lag' and then do the difference

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   mutate(lag = value - lag(value),
          perc = lag/lag(value))
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   type [3]
#    year type  value   lag    perc
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1  2000 A        71    NA  NA    
# 2  2000 B        80    NA  NA    
# 3  2000 C        99    NA  NA    
# 4  2002 A        79     8   0.113
# 5  2002 B        61   -19  -0.238
# 6  2002 C        62   -37  -0.374
# 7  2003 A        56   -23  -0.291
# 8  2003 B        88    27   0.443
# 9  2003 C        50   -12  -0.194
#10  2006 A        85    29   0.518
#11  2006 B        56   -32  -0.364
#12  2006 C        85    35   0.7
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(year, type, value)
```

Comment: It is what I did! I did it with an `arrange(year)` as well. It does not work on my side, neither with my df nor with my example. (with this exaple I have the following error message: "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : ")

Comment: @TeYaP  I am using only your example, but not with a matrix (`cbind` -creates a `matrix`), but on a `data.frame` (check my data).  It is working fine for me

Comment: I mean, it does work with this example but not with my full df

Comment: @TeYaP  If you can provide the dput of a small example that doesn't work, then it would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `ave` to calculate *lag* with `diff` and calculation of percentage change:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(year, type, value)

df <- within(df, {
          lag <- ave(value, type, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
          prev <- ave(value, type, FUN=function(x) c(NA, x[1:length(x)-1]))

          pct <- ifelse(is.na(prev), NA, lag / prev)
          rm(prev)
    })

df

#    year type value        pct lag
# 1  2000    A    71         NA  NA
# 2  2000    B    80         NA  NA
# 3  2000    C    99         NA  NA
# 4  2002    A    79  0.1126761   8
# 5  2002    B    61 -0.2375000 -19
# 6  2002    C    62 -0.3737374 -37
# 7  2003    A    56 -0.2911392 -23
# 8  2003    B    88  0.4426230  27
# 9  2003    C    50 -0.1935484 -12
# 10 2006    A    85  0.5178571  29
# 11 2006    B    56 -0.3636364 -32
# 12 2006    C    85  0.7000000  35
```